# how to reload CheckboxListTile in flutter (dart)?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-alertdialog, checkboxlist, showdialog

I simple code below

```
RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Form(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                    ................
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    model.delete();
                  }),
            ],
          );
        });
```

.................

```
Expanded(
    child: model.isBusy
    ? CircularProgressIndicator()
    : ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: model.listinit.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return CheckboxListTile(
            value: true,
            onChanged: (value) {
               .....
            },
            activeColor: Colors.green,
    );
```

Note that the above code is in the same class

I want when I press button (model.delete -> delete one item in list). `CheckboxListTile` of me will reload(listinit)

ex:

`CheckboxListTile` of me have 10 item

`AlertDialog` display and I delete 1 item. after I close `AlertDialog` then list of me will display 9 item.

sorry bacause english of me bad, please help me

Comment: you can do it by  adding  setState under of   model.delete();

Comment: I not using setState. I using notifielistiner()

Comment: try to add your model and function delete,

Comment: I try but it not work. can you help me edit

Comment: add code of your your model :)

Comment: class ViewModel extends FutureViewModel {
         listnit = ....
}

Comment: I dont see anygthng add it to the question not in the comment